# owa_util.mime_header Issue - Trying to extract a Excel File from a query

Tags: sql, excel, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

'm having a problem with my one procedure that suppose to generate an Excel file, the procedure is this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GENERATE_REPORT_P(P_CONTRACT_NUM      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                              P_CUSTOMER_NAME     IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                              P_CUSTOMER_NUM      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                              P_UPDATE_DATE_START IN DATE DEFAULT NULL,
                              P_UPDATE_DATE_END   IN DATE DEFAULT NULL,
                              P_ORDER_NUM         IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL) IS

  vRecords BOOLEAN := FALSE;
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT 
                     a.contract_num,
                     d.customer_abt_number,
                     d.customer_name,
                     c.doms_order_num order_num,
                     e.service_tag asset,
                     e.sku,
                     e.field,
                     e.previous_value,
                     e.new_value,
                     e.update_date, --to_char(i.update_date, 'DD-MON-RRRR HH12:MI:SS')
                     e.updated_by
                FROM contracts       a,
                     order_extension b,
                     orders          c,
                     customers       d,
                     abt_cisi_log    e
               WHERE a.id = b.contract_id
                 AND c.id = b.order_id
                 AND d.id = a.customer_id
                 AND c.id = e.order_id
                    --parameters
                 AND a.contract_num LIKE NVL(p_contract_num, a.contract_num)
                 AND d.customer_abt_number LIKE
                     NVL(p_customer_num, d.customer_abt_number)
                 AND d.customer_name LIKE
                     NVL(p_customer_name, d.customer_name)
                 AND e.update_date between
                     NVL(to_date(p_update_date_start, 'dd-mon-rrrr'), '01-JAN-1900') AND
                     NVL(to_date(p_update_date_end, 'dd-mon-rrrr'), '31-DEC-2199')
                 AND c.doms_order_num LIKE
                     NVL(p_order_num, c.doms_order_num)
               ORDER BY a.contract_num,
                        c.doms_order_num,
                        e.service_tag,
                        e.sku) LOOP

      IF NOT vRecords THEN
        vRecords := TRUE;
        owa_util.mime_header(ccontent_type => 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
        htp.htmlopen;
        htp.bodyopen;
        htp.tableopen(cattributes => 'border=1');
        htp.tablerowopen;
        htp.p('<td><b>Contract</b></td>');
        htp.p('<td><b>Customer Number</b></td>');
        htp.p('<td><b>Customer</b></td>');
        htp.p('<td><b>Order#</b></td>');
        htp.p('<td><b>Asset</b></td>');
        htp.p('<td><b>SKU</b></td>');
        htp.p('<td><b>Field</b></td>');
        htp.p('<td><b>Previous Value</b></td>');
        htp.p('<td><b>New Value</b></td>');
        htp.p('<td><b>Update Date</b></td>');
        htp.p('<td><b>Updated By</b></td>');
        htp.tablerowclose;
      END IF;
      htp.tablerowopen;
      htp.p('<td>' || i.contract_num || '</td>');
      htp.p('<td>' || i.customer_abt_number || '</td>');
      htp.p('<td>' || i.customer_name || '</td>');
      htp.p('<td>' || i.order_num || '</td>');
      htp.p('<td>' || i.asset || '</td>');
      htp.p('<td>' || i.sku || '</td>');
      htp.p('<td>' || i.field || '</td>');
      htp.p('<td>' || i.previous_value || '</td>');
      htp.p('<td>' || i.new_value || '</td>');
      htp.p('<td>' || to_char(i.update_date, 'DD-MON-RRRR HH12:MI:SS') ||
            '</td>');
      htp.p('<td>' || i.updated_by || '</td>');
      htp.tablerowclose;
    END LOOP;

    IF vRecords THEN
      htp.tableclose;
      htp.bodyclose;
      htp.htmlclose;
    END IF;
  END GENERATE_REPORT_P;
```

But when i execute this procedure by 
Begin 
  GENERATE_REPORT_P();
END;

I ALWAYS get this error:

[image]

I was trying to figure it out, but not much luclk until now, I've tryed to comment all the code into the procedure and just call the `owa_util.mime_header(ccontent_type => 'application/vnd.ms-excel');` To see what happens, and checked the data type from my table, well, pretty much all the basic stuff.

If anyone could give me some help, ou tip, i really appreciate that. 
My Regards!

Note: I extract the procedure from a packge, and ajust one or two things just to place at StackOverflow, so, i u see the error message and figere it out, my bad!

Comment: Btw. are you sure that what you are sending to your HTTP output **truly is** a content of the `application/vnd.ms-excel` mime type?

Comment: i'm not sure about it @nop77svk i dont have much experience with this kind of thing, i'm trying to figure it out to help a developer from my team, how could i check this out?!

Comment: OK, Yuri, the problem I see is exactly this: The content you are generating via the HTP package is an HTML content, not a XLS content. Alas, I can't help you with sending XLS data to the caller. That "smells" of Fusion MiddleWare or Oracle iAS and I don't know how to work with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this particular issue put this piece of code somewhere before the call to `generate_report_p`:

```
owa.num_cgi_vars := NVL(owa.num_cgi_vars, 0);
```

Comment: Thx for thid tip, i will try this and see what could happen

Comment: I've tryedm and it work, but not at all, the error gone, but, the excel file dosent show up! any ideia? and, sorry for take too long to answer you. @nop77svk